# How to quickly test if a TypeMirror is a subtype of another

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I am using mirrors and would like to determine if one ClassMirror is a subtype of another.  Sort of something like:

```dart
ClassMirror type = me.getField(someSymbol).type;

// obviously this won't work, since a ClassMirror is not a List
if(type.originalDeclaration is List) {
    ...
}
```

Really I'm looking for something like Java's Class.isAssignableFrom(Class), i.e, a first order isa operator.  Walking up the type hierarchy myself feels a bit klunky, especially in the presence of mixins, and would (hopefully) be slower than what the dart runtime / compiler could provide.  Is there a built-in method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TypeMirror.isSubtypeOf()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/dev/#dart-mirrors.TypeMirror@id_isSubtypeOf), [TypeMirror.isAssignableTo()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/dev/#dart-mirrors.TypeMirror@id_isAssignableTo), [ClassMirror.isSubclassOf()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/dev/#dart-mirrors.ClassMirror@id_isSubclassOf) have been added in Dart 1.2. (As of writing this is the dev channel, They should appear in the next Dart stable release.)

Comment: Only a little over than two years it took to implement this feature. I am silent about possible bugs that can appear.

Comment: Thanks for flagging that Greg, and to the Dart team for finally implementing this.  I can now accept the acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, checking the type would look like this.

```dart
ClassMirror type = me.getField(someSymbol).type;
// you could also use type.qualifiedName (dart.core.List)
if (type.originalDeclaration.simpleName == #List) {
    ...
}
```

But you would still have to walk up the type hierarchy.

Once this bug https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12607 is fixed, you could do it this way (if you are not compiling to javascript, it does already work https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6433):

```dart
ClassMirror type = me.getField(someSymbol).type;
if (type.reflectedType == List) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This still requires searching the hierarchy, which seems like a silly way of doing things.  I wonder why the mirror system can't query the type lattice?

Comment: I have filed a defect, which has passed triage, https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13856, so it seems your answer is the only solution at this time.

Comment: FWIW you can now use symbol literals! Instead of `const Symbol('List')` you can simply use `#List`.